# Adding attachment file to product option in Kentico

Tags: kentico

Am creating Book store using Kentico CMS the book would be different Languages so i've created product option called **Book Language** then i assigned every product if there are English or French or whatever available languages but the problem here is that i need to upload with each option PDF file and image for each available option of the product, i used to add the pdfs in attachment tap with flag like English File to know which one is belong to which language but i think it should be some practice better than this, can any one help??

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple thoughts, and you may need to create additional interfaces to manage this.

Each Product Option is really a row in the COM_SKU table with "SKUOptionCategoryID" set and i believe SKUParentSKUID set (been a while).  So it does have a unique SKUID from that table.

If you could tie that into the COM_SKUFile table through the API or through another interface, you should be able to leverage that.

Whether or not you can do it with default Kentico interface, not 100%.